# WPF XAML syntax for including resource as xml element rather than as property

Tags: wpf, xaml, syntax

I've got this working:

```
    <Button Content="{StaticResource SaveImage}" />
```

But now I want to make the button a little more complicated

```
        <Button>
            <Button.Content>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                    {StaticResource SaveImage} <!-- WHAT GOES HERE?? -->
                    <Label>Save</Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </Button.Content>
        </Button>
```

How do I place the image resource in the xml tree, rather than just assigning it to a property to the Button class?

Note, the resource is defined like:

```
<Image x:Key="SaveImage" x:Shared="False" Source="Save.png" Height="16" Width="16"/>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use a `StaticResource` directly. Try it like this

```
<Button>
    <Button.Content>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
            <StaticResource ResourceKey="SaveImage"/>
            <Label>Save</Label>
        </StackPanel>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: That seems to do the trick!  Although for me, it's <StaticResourceExtension /> not <StaticResource /> -- maybe that's a 3.5 -> 4.0 difference?

Comment: @Clyde: It should be `<StaticResource..` for both 3.5 and 4.0. Are you sure it's not just the intellisence messing with you? :)

Comment: Well, just <StaticResource does seem to work, and at least superficially behaves the same as <StaticResourceExtension.  But you're right, the intellisense was messing with me.

Comment: @Clyde the StaticResource element is defined in StaticResourceExtension, your auto suggest is just picking up the extension rather than the element

Answer (score 0):

```
<Image Source="{StaticResource SaveImage}"/>
```

Comment: The source property of an Image can, itself, be another Image?  See above where I've added the definition of my resource.

Comment: Your resource needs to be a BitmapSource, e.g. BitmapImage

Comment: this would work if you changed SaveImage to an image source (ie bitmapImage) rather than an image element, which is how you should do it

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to go in most of these situations is just to use content control inside

```
<Button>
   <ContentControl Content="{StaticResource whatever}" />
</Button>
```